# Default checked option in primeng multiselect

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to select one option by default using primeng multiselect(angular 7). I am able to select 1 option by default but check box for that option is not getting checked but it's coming in my selected option array. I am displaying that default option as defaultLable on label field of primeng multiselect just for look ad feel. Any one has nay idea how we can make checkbox checked for default selected option.

I tried to put item in to select Array initially, and then displayed using defaultLable

Comment: make a stackblitz demo!! with your code and stack community can look after it

Answer (score 3):

just give as value of the multiselect an array with the first value.
from the [docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect)

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cars" [(ngModel)]="selectedCars" 
      [panelStyle]="{minWidth:'12em'}">
</p-multiSelect>

cars = [
    {label: 'Audi', value: 'Audi'},
    {label: 'BMW', value: 'BMW'},
    {label: 'Fiat', value: 'Fiat'}
]
selectedCars=[cars[0].value]
```